# How to Store attributes as key value Pair in yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to store attributes for the product as dynamic attributes.For eg color,type,amount fields are dynamic fields which is added by admin.Its stored under attributes table.

I want to add a product based on this dynamic attributes. Any Idea to do this in Yii2. I think its possible with loadmultiple feature of yii2. Any Idea.. Pls help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow isn't a forum, it is about solving concrete problems.

Comment: How did you solve your task?

Answer (score 0):

I'll create a table 'attributes' related to 'products' table.

In the 'attributes' table I'll put 2 fields: type and value.

Type could be 'color', 'type', 'amount', ...
Value could be 'red', 'small', '10.34', ...

Then You should manipulate value based on type.

Comment: Then how to insert data to products table based on this attributes?

Comment: You should insert the product in 'products' table and then create its attributes in 'attributes' table

Comment: Fabrizio Caldarelli do you have the code for storing the values of products to database.. pl

Comment: $product = new Product(); ....; $product->save();    $attr = new ProductAttribute(); $attr->product_id = $product->id; $attr->attributes = ['type' => 'color', 'value' => 'red']; $attr->save();

Comment: Thanks. Whata the structure of the product attributes table? Is attributes are stored as an array?

Comment: The structure is a row for a single attribute of the product

Comment: Can you explain this line in your codeattr->attributes = ['type' => 'color', 'value' => 'red'];

Comment: That line fill 'type' and 'value' fields of 'attributes' record with value 'color' and 'red'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106020/discussion-between-sarin-surendran-and-fabrizio-caldarelli).